# Finding exact value of trigonometric functions

Tags: trigonometry

I was wondering, how do I get the exact fraction (the value) of this trigonometric function:

$$\cos\left(\sin^{-1}(12/13)+\sin^{-1}(4/5)\right)$$

Usually, I would evaluate the inverse sin in degree mode and multiply (by hand) by $\pi/180$.

But in this case, I don't get exact values of angles

For example :

$$\begin{eqnarray}
\sin^{-1}(12/13)=67,38...^\circ\\
\sin^{-1}(4/5)=53,13...^\circ
\end{eqnarray}
$$
Is there any way of doing it ?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT:

Let $A=\arcsin\dfrac{12}{13}$

Using the [definition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_trigonometric_functions#Principal_values) of Principal value of $\arcsin,0<A<\dfrac\pi2$

$\implies \cos A=+\sqrt{1-\sin^2A}=\dfrac5{13}$

Comment: ok, I found a way, not sure if you were referring to this : cos(arcsin(12/13)+arcsin(4/5))=cos(arcsin(12/13)cos(arcsin(4/5)-sin(arcsin(12/13))+sin(arcsin(4/5))

Comment: @Astroman, Please share your method

Comment: After, you just have to evaluate the two cos ( cos(arcsin(12/13) and cos(arcsin(4/5)) with your explanation

Comment: @Astroman, What's $\cos(A+B)$

Comment: well, A=arcsin(12/13 and B=arcsin(4/5

Comment: oh, you mean : cos(A+B)=cos A cos B - sin A sin B

Comment: @Astroman, Yes, so we need all four $:\cos A,\cos B,\sin A,\sin B$

Comment: Ok, well that's exactly what I did. (see the answer that I gave) Anyway, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

We have:
$$\arcsin\frac{4}{5} = \arg(3+4i),\qquad \arcsin\frac{12}{13}=\arg(5+12i), $$
hence:
$$\arcsin\frac{4}{5}+\arcsin\frac{12}{13}=\arg((3+4i)(5+12i))=\arg(-33+56i)$$
and:
$$ \cos\left(\arcsin\frac{4}{5}+\arcsin\frac{12}{13}\right)=\frac{-33}{\sqrt{33^2+56^2}}=-\frac{33}{65}.$$

---

Avoiding complex numbers.
$$\arcsin\frac{4}{5} = \arctan\frac{4}{3},\qquad \arcsin\frac{12}{13}=\arctan\frac{12}{5}, $$
so:
$$\arcsin\frac{4}{5}+\arcsin\frac{12}{13}=\arctan\frac{\frac{4}{3}+\frac{12}{5}}{1-\frac{4}{3}\cdot\frac{12}{5}}=\arctan\left(-\frac{56}{33}\right) $$
and:
$$\cos\arctan\left(-\frac{56}{33}\right)=\frac{-33}{\sqrt{33^2+56^2}}=-\frac{33}{56}.$$

Comment: I don't even know what arg() means... And  we're only working with real numbers. Thank you again for you answer)

Comment: @Astroman: I just added another proof using only the sum formula for the tangent function.

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\, #1 \,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\, #1 \,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\, #1 \,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil\, #1 \,\right\rceil\,}
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\dsc}[1]{\displaystyle{\color{red}{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\Li}[1]{\,{\rm Li}_{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\, #1 \,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\vphantom{\large A}\,#2\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}&\color{#66f}{\large%
\cos\pars{\arcsin\pars{12 \over 13} + \arcsin\pars{4 \over 5}}}
\\[5mm]&=\cos\pars{\arcsin\pars{12 \over 13}}\cos\pars{\arcsin\pars{4 \over 5}}
-\
\overbrace{\sin\pars{\arcsin\pars{12 \over 13}}}^{\dsc{12 \over 13}}\
\overbrace{\sin\pars{\arcsin\pars{4 \over 5}}}^{\dsc{4 \over 5}}
\\[5mm]&=\root{1 - \sin^{2}\pars{\arcsin\pars{12 \over 13}}}
\root{1 - \sin^{2}\pars{\arcsin\pars{4 \over 5}}}\ -\ {12 \over 13}\,{4 \over 5}
\\[5mm]&=\root{1 - \pars{12 \over 13}^{2}}
\root{1 - \pars{4 \over 5}^{2}} - {48 \over 65}
={3 \over 13} - {48 \over 65}=\color{#66f}{\large -\,{33 \over 65}}
\end{align}